# Highlight rows based on cell input with JS in Rshiny data tables package

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I've been trying to use the rowCallback argument in the options list of datatable. It doesn't kill the app, but when run as is, the table doesn't load to the page. ATS is the column of the data table and every row with the value "Covered" in ATS should be a different colour row than the others. This is my first attempt at using javaScript in shiny so I'm not sure why the table isn't displaying. Any suggestions as to what is wrong? 
Cheers

```
    createdRow = I(
    "function(row, data) {
    if (parseFloat(data[5]) <= -11.0)
    $(row).css('background-color', 'red');
    else 
    $(row).css('background-color', '#00adff');
    });
}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually prefer to use the built-in functions than to create my own custom JavaScript. In this case you could make use of [formatStyle](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html). It works great for numeric or for coloring based on a certain String value:

```
library(DT)
mtcars$cyl=as.character(mtcars$cyl)
 datatable(mtcars) %>% formatStyle('cyl',
  target = 'row',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("6"), c('#00adff'))
)
```

[image]

You can add multiple rules as `styleEqual(c("6","5"), c('#00adff',"green"))`, but as far as I know it does not contain the option for an if-else construction with strings. It does so for numeric, so we can create a 'helper' column to base the row colors on, and use columnDefs to hide that column from the result:

```
 mtcars$cyl = as.character(mtcars$cyl)
 mtcars$helper = mtcars$cyl=="6"
 datatable(mtcars,options=list(columnDefs = 
        list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=which(colnames(mtcars)=='helper'))))) %>% 
  formatStyle('helper', target = 'row',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1,0), c('#EDEDED','#00adff')))
```

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: I just found that solution, thanks so much! I'm now stuck on a similar problem where the styleEqual isn't as helpful. I need to highlight rows where the column cell is >= a certain number. I've tried many different java Script examples and have been unsuccessful. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can try StyleInterval: `backgroundColor = styleInterval(6, c('', 'green')))` colors all rows where the value is larger than 6 for example. Would you please consider accepting this answer if it was helpful? Thanks

Comment: okay last one, what about a range of values. Say 1 < cell < 10?

Comment: You can also do that with StyleInterval, there i a really good example of that specific case [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) (the second one under 2. style table cells)